# Corona SDK: Bottom Banner Ad Not Showing

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm developing an android app with ads in corona sdk using admob but when I try to display an ad at the bottom of the screen by setting Y to 100000 the ad doesn't show at all. It shows at the top of the screen when Y = 0. Here is my code:

```
local ads = require( "ads" )
local bannerAppID = "The App ID"
local adProvider = "admob"
local function adListener( event )

end
ads.init( adProvider, bannerAppID, adListener )

ads.show( "banner", { x=0, y=100000, appId=bannerAppID } )
```

Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the bottom of your screen is at y=100000?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup your admob account and app properly, make sure you add this to your build.setting file:

```
settings =
{
    plugins =
    {
        ["plugin.google.play.services"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
        },
    },      
}
```